# Handlebars not recognized as an operable command in Windows

Tags: handlebars.js

> 'handlebars' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

This error occur even after I installed handlebars on my system.

Here's how I installed the program:

```
npm install handlebars -g
```

I successfully installed it but still got that issue after I typed in `handlebars` on the command line.

Comment: It should show the details of the program. Same when you typed in npm where it shows the list of commands that you can use.

Comment: Am I doing the right thing in installing handlebars?

`npm install handlebars -g`

Or do I miss something?

Comment: I think its a module you can add on npm. So basically, its an executable program. I was able to use it on my mac device. I just got this problem on windows.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js#differences-between-handlebarsjs-and-mustache, it seems that the command you used installs the handlebars precompiler. I admit I would expect it to run by typing `handlebars`. However, you should find out what folder it installed into, and add that folder to your path.

Comment: I added `-g` on the command so it will be available globally.

Comment: That doesn't change what I actually said. Find out where it was installed, and make sure that location is in your path.

Comment: It's ok now. I placed the wrong directory to my path. Thank you @JohnSaunders Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

In windows sometimes the PATH environment variable is not set up properly or is there bu does not work after node.js is installed.

I found I could run handlebars by using its full path:

C:\Users\ [your windows user] \AppData\Roaming\npm\handlebars.cmd

Answer (score 0):

The handlebars command line program is located in appdata/roaming, I don't know why it is but that's where it installed to. I left it there and created a command prompt leading to that location and then used the following to precompile my files.

Your handlebars program should be in the following location:

C:\Users\YourProfileNameHere\AppData\Roaming\npm\

**EDIT: Apologize - use the following handlebars directory instead of the one above for, for some reason it does not compile the file correctly. Also use this for the remainder of the procedure.**

C:\Users\YourProfileNameHere\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\handlebars\bin**

The following will make a command prompt file directly to the above location or wherever npm installed your handlebars program, modify the following if that is true:

1. copy the command line icon somewhere, desktop is easiest and rename it "Handlebars Cmd Prompt"
2. go to properties and insert the following into the Target option:

%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k "cd C:\Users\YourProfileNameHere\AppData\Roaming\npm" -

**EDIT: REPLACE THE ABOVE FILE PATH WITH THE FOLLOWING:
C:\Users\YourProfileNameHere\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\handlebars\bin**

--this will ensure that the command prompt points directly to the handlebars program folder instead of desktop

3. in the "Start in" option copy your file location (as follows) to the handlebars program, of course with your profile name inserted.

C:\Users\YourProfileNameHere\AppData\Roaming\npm

**EDIT: REPLACE THE ABOVE FILE PATH WITH THE FOLLOWING:
C:\Users\YourProfileNameHere\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\handlebars\bin**

To make a .js template file:

1. copy the template data inside your HTML file to a separate file, name it but do not put an extension on it
2. Open up your new Handlebars Cmd Prompt
3. Type the following (of course it's all on the same line with proper spacing).

**EDITED THE FOLLOWING FILE PATH TO THE CORRECT PATH**
C:\Users\YourProfileNameHere\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\handlebars\bin>handlebars C:\FullpathtoYourProjectHTMLFileFolderHere\NameofTheNewTemplateFileYouMadeIn#1Above -f C:\FullPathWhereYouWantYourNew .js FileToBe(likely in your HTML project file location)

Hope that helps to get you going!